# PG::ConnectionBad error while trying to run sidekiq server on a rails app on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sidekiq, sequel

I am using Windows for my development.

Here is the error I get while starting up the sidekiq server for this Rails application using Postgres RDS on AWS:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: timeout expired
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:243:in 'initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:243:in 'new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sequel-4.36.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:243:in 'connect'
```

I checked the Postgres server logs on AWS and it says:

```
[12826]:LOG: could not accept SSL connection: Connection reset by peer"
```

My gemfile is using Sequel and sequel_pg. I'm not sure if they are causing the error.

Same Postgres database connections work fine on another Rails application without Sidekiq.

Comment: I resolved this by reinstalling pg gem.. (on windows 10)

reinstall PG gem.. (pg-0.18.4-x86-mingw32.gem)
 gem uninstall pg
 gem install pg

Also use following versions of 
sequel (4.29.0)
    sequel-rails (0.9.11)
      actionpack (>= 3.2.0)
      activemodel
      railties (>= 3.2.0)
      sequel (>= 3.28, < 5.0)
    sequel_pg (1.6.10)
      pg (>= 0.8.0)
      sequel (>= 3.39.0)
    sequel_pg (1.6.10-x86-mingw32)
      pg (>= 0.8.0)
      sequel (>= 3.39.0)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if sidekiq is preloading the app and then forking, but if so, you want to make sure you disconnect the Sequel database connections before forking.